# Flutter class not initialized

Tags: flutter, class, object, initialization, getter-setter

I am using a login on my app and I am trying to use getter and setter for my User class. I can't get the values from the class because the app says not initialised.

First I sign up from my profile screen so I need a check if it is initialised or not here I guess otherwise it crashes here.

(This is profile screen)
`if (User().name) { print('user email from get: ${User().name}'); }`

Then from register screen:
`User().setName = usernameController.text;`

User go to profile screen to sign up and then if success goes back to profile screen.
And will the program know it is the 'same' user object I use?
Is there a way to check the class value from getter in profile if it is not initialised yet?
If it is initialised in future I want to just display it.

I have tried User().name.isEmpty & .isNotEmpty and it crashed with Field not initialized.

Comment: Everytime you write `User()` you are creating a new user. You need to store it in a variable and use that same variable everywhere

Comment: Ok, but can I declare it inside let's say my sign up screen and then I have to pass it everywhere I navigate? Or is there a way to have one variable that I can use everywhere? @Ivo

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are describing is one of state management. You need to be able to hold the state of variables, and access that data from different parts of your app.

There are several different state management techniques available for Flutter apps, and the Provider package (which if officially recommended by the Flutter team) is a great place to start for simple apps.

Here's an official Flutter guide using the Provider package:
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

And here's the Provider package: https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Answer (score -1):

**@Robban13** Please use the below package to save and reflect/use your data anywhere in the application

https://pub.dev/packages/get_it

GetIt is **a service locator that allows you to create interfaces and their implementations, and access those implementations globally, anywhere in your app.**